# css opacity problems when moving over a div inside the div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that has an opacity of 0. Now when I hover over it, the opacity changes to 1. (well known jquery stuff that I won't paste in here). I put text in that div and it all works fine. However, whenever I put that text in a div, or inside anything basically, it changes the opacity back to 0 and then again to 1.

That's annoying as it is, but if I just move my mouse over it to and fro, it makes it start to blink, etc. etc. How can I fix this?

The code for the opacity is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".jshover").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 300);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 300)
    });
});
```

Code of the div is:

```
<div id="ww11">
  <div id="ww11o" class="jshover">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
  <b>More...</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `[]` instead of `<>` for the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the stop method to stop the blinking effect

```
$(this).stop().animate({...
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qhQ6p/)

Comment: Thank you Joseph! That did the trick.. and is very easy fix actually! Thanks also for the demo.. it shows me exactly what to do!!
Also thank you Brent for your comment.. I'll keep it in mind!
(I thought I had it set up so that I would receive an email whenever there was a reply.. never got anything, so I'm glad I just checked! :-) )

Answer (score 3):

use mouseenter and mouseleave events. they are not called again when mouse over children object.

Comment: those are jquery, mootools and etc events too.

Comment: oh! nice.  Didn't know jQuery implemented that.  They can't be using the native event.